# Asp.net Core 2.1 or 2.2 BOT SDK 4 invalid activity-missing Conversation.Id error when accessing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-appservice

I'm trying to get the To number from Twilio before initiating ProcessAsync in the Bot Controller.

If I use FromForm like below, I can get the To parameter, but I get the "invalid activity-missing Conversation.Id" error in the Dialog.

```
public async Task PostAsync([FromForm] string To )
{
}
```

If I use Request.Form["To"] like below, I can get the To parameter, but I get the "invalid activity-missing Conversation.Id" error in the Dialog.

```
public async Task PostAsync()
{
  Request.Form["To"]
}
```

Does anyone know, why this is happening and/or how to fix it? The BOT works just fine if I don't ask for any Parameters in the Bot Controller.

The Controller is decorated with `[ApiController]`.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Looks like it was an issue with the Request and reading it twice. The key is to reset the Request back to 0, so the Bot Adapter can read it.

```
            var req = Request;

            // Allows using the stream several times in ASP.Net Core
            req.EnableRewind();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["To"]))
            {
                toNumber = Request.Form["To"];
            }

            // Rewind, so the core is not lost when the Bot Adapter looks for the body in the request
            req.Body.Position = 0;
```